# Importar código de arquivo JavaScript externo

Tags: javascript

No CSS, tem o `@import` que eu consigo chamar o código de um arquivo externo dentro do meu arquivo atual. Exemplo:

```
@import 'font-awesome/css/all.min.css';
```

Gostaria de saber se existe como fazer algo semelhante a isso no JavaScript? No caso, fazer um "import" de todo o conteúdo de um arquivo JavaScript dentro de outro.

Answer (score 0):

***Olá, boa tarde!***

Um dos jeitos possíveis de fazer isso é através de ***módulos***, nesse caso a sintaxe é bem simples, vamos supor que você queira exportar uma função:

***function.js***

```
export function helloWorld(){
    console.log('Hello world')
}
```

***main.js***

```
import { helloWorld } from './function.js';
helloWorld();
```

Minha explicação foi bem breve, porém você pode conferir uma ***documentação completa*** no site Mozila Developer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/M%C3%B3dulos

***Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!***

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas acho que o quem o fez foi motivado por essa frase *"import" de todo o conteúdo de um arquivo JavaScript dentro de outro.*  o que implica em algo parecido com `var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = CAMINHO_DO_SCRIPT;` ou então algo parecido com o [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: @AugustoVasques seria algo no sentido do que você falou mesmo. Poderia compartilhar como resposta pra mim marcar?

Comment: Você quer o meu comentário como resposta? Não! É apenas um comentário orientando o AR qual o rumo a direcionar a resposta. Não possui qualquer intuito cabal ou remoto em fornecer solução a pergunta.